# Add button overlay on UITableViewController with use static cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

I try to add **button overlay** on **UITableViewController** with **static cells**. But i get this result, button is working, but i not see result of search:

[image]

I'm trying to get this result:

[image]

I want to button was always at the bottom regardless of **scrolling up or down**.

In my code i use framework **InstantSearch**:

```
import UIKit
import InstantSearch
import WARangeSlider

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultButton: StatsButtonWidget!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resultButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 60)
        navigationController?.view.addSubview(resultButton)

        InstantSearch.shared.registerAllWidgets(in: self.view)

        LayoutHelpers.setupResultButton(button: resultButton)
        resultButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(resultButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

    }
}
```

How can i add **button overlay** on bottom in **UITableViewController**? Me need use only UITableViewController, not UIViewController with TableView.

Comment: Subclass a `UIViewController`, add your `UITableViewController` as its child view controller. Your subclass should hold the `UITableViewController.view` and a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an view at the bottom of your tableview.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addResultButtonView()
}

private func addResultButtonView() {
    let resultButton = UIButton()

    resultButton.backgroundColor = .red
    resultButton.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
    tableView.addSubview(resultButton)

    // set position
    resultButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    resultButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    resultButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    resultButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    resultButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    resultButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true // specify the height of the view
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could directly add the button to the `UITableView` without `AutoLayout`, and make sure TableView's `delegate` is the controller, like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tableView.frame.size.height - 50, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: 50)
    self.tableView.addSubview(self.button)
    self.tableView.delegate = self
}
```

Then you are able to **fix** the button's position by UIScrollView delegate (UITableViewDelegate inherited from this) while TableView is scrolling:

```
public func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == self.tableView) {
        let originY = scrollView.frame.size.height - self.button.frame.size.height + scrollView.contentOffset.y
        self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: originY, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: self.button.frame.size.height)
    } 
}
```

**Alternatively**, if you want to position the button by AutoLayout, just define a `NSLayoutConstraint` property, and bind it to button's bottom space constraint to its super view. Then adjust the constraint's constant value by same mechanism in `scrollViewDidScroll` function.